# Obtaining a Modified Version of SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd

I have some complex matrix, $M$, which has dimensions ,$m \times 1$.

I can perform a SVD on this matrix and get,

$$
M  = ASV^{\dagger}
$$

where $S$ and $V$ are a $1 \times 1$ matrices and $V$ is unitary (so it has to look like $e^{i\theta}$) and $A$ has dimensions $m \times 1$ and satisfies $A^{\dagger}A = (1)$.

Is there some way to modify the SVD so that $AA^{\dagger} = I$ and $A$ has dimensions $m \times 1$ instead (where $I$ is the $m \times m$ identity matrix)?
If not, is there a decomposition that I can perform on $M$, that has this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not possible: an $m\times1$ matrix has at most rank one, so $AA^\dagger=I$ is impossible.

In the [usual Singular Value Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), applied to your $M$, the matrix $A$ is an $m\times m$ unitary (so $A^\dagger A=AA^\dagger=I$), $S$ is $m\times 1$, and $V$ is $1\times1$.

Comment: I still want to preserve the fact that $A$ has dimensions $m \times 1$.

Comment: Then you don't want to "modify the decomposition". No matrix $A$ like that exists, regardless of what you put to the right of it.

Comment: What if I didn't want to do an SVD? Can this be achieved with another type of decomposition with $M$?

Comment: So I guess the question is can I write $M$ = $AB$, where $A$ satisfies the property I want and has dimension $m \times 1$

Comment: No, that's what I told you can't be done: if $A$ is $m\times 1$, then it is rank-one and so $AA^\dagger=I$ (which implies that $A$ is invertible, so rank $m$) is impossible.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you